# Activate SSL-Certificate on Domain via Plesk XML API

Tags: xml-rpc, plesk, zend-xmlrpc

I'm currently working on a Plesk-Panel Plugin for automatically getting & installing SSL-certificates.
With the very powerful [XML API](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/) provided by Parallels I'm able to install the certificate to Plesks SSL Cert-Pool.

It's also possible to [turn SSL on](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/index.htm?fileName=66557.htm) for a specific page, but I can absolutely find no way to activate a specific certificate (which is, of course, already added to the certificate pool).

The easiest answer of course would be "the API doesn't support it",
but it's very easy to do this via the Command Line Utilities using this command:

`/opt/psa/bin/subscription -u example.com -certificate-name my_cool_ssl_cert`

and regarding to [the manual](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-extensions-guide/71088.htm#),

> The Command-Line Interface (CLI) has the same functions as API RPC

which is relatively obvious, because they have the same functionality everywhere else.

So what point do I miss? Has anybody done this before?

Without the possibility to activate a specific via the XML-API, many of the calls would be completely senseless (It's possible to install a CERT, activate ssl but not to activate it? Can't really believe this.)

I'd really appreciate any answer/comment that points me to the right direction, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the request example:

```
<packet>
    <webspace>
        <set>
            <filter>
                <id>34</id>
            </filter>
            <values>
                <hosting>
                    <vrt_hst>

                        <property>

                            <name>certificate_name</name>

                            <value>some_existed_certificate_name</value>

                        </property>

                    </vrt_hst>
                </hosting>
            </values>
        </set>  
    </webspace>
</packet>
```

Main rule is that if in CLI it's an "subscription" setting, than we go to  "Managing Subscriptions (Webspaces)" -> "Setting Subscription Parameters" and we always have to check "Request Packet Structure". From packet structure we guess that our SSL setting should be in hosting part and there is a link, so we going to

```
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/39967.htm
```

but there we see that this part of API is not fully documented, there some "properties" but obviously not all of them. And there is a note

> Note: To manage hosting settings, you should first retrieve a hosting
>   settings     descriptor, containing names of the settings. For
>   details, refer to the [Retrieving  Descriptor of Hosting Settings](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/40011.htm)
>   section.

And by this new link we can find how to retrieve an list of all names of hosting properties where we find "certificate_name".

For addon domain or subdomain you can use following query:

```
<packet>
    <site>
        <set>
            <filter>
                <id>3</id>
            </filter>
            <values>
                <hosting>
                    <vrt_hst>

                        <property>

                            <name>certificate_name</name>

                            <value>some_existed_certificate_name</value>

                        </property>

                    </vrt_hst>
                </hosting>
            </values>
        </set>  
    </site>
</packet>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm _really_ ashamed i haven't found it in the manual :-/

Comment: Well, it's really not easy, I've updated answer to describe how I've find this parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the REST API to create subdomains and is working great and..its way more clear the setup..you might not find enough documentation but if you try things you will see that it's working just fine..i think faster too but that's not the point..
So here is what i do to install SSL, ftp user, PHP Version etc..

```
$new_store = array(
  "name"              => newstore.sudbomain.com,
  "description"       => 'New store example',
  "hosting_type"      => 'virtual',

  'hosting_settings'  => array(
    "www_root"        => 'Clients/newstore.sudbomain.com,
    'ftp_login'       => $this->_ftp_user,
    'ftp_password'    => $this->_ftp_pass,
    'php'             => true,
    'php_handler_id'  => 'plesk-php80-fpm',
    'certificate_name'=> 'WildCardSSL'
  ),

  "parent_domain"       => array(
    "id"              => $this->_ng_id,
    "name"            => $this->_ng_name,
    "guid"            => $this->_ng_guid
  ),

  "ip_addresses"      => ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"],
  "ipv4"              => ["XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"],
  "ipv6"              => ["xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx::x"]

);

$body = json_encode($new_store, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$this->api_call('domains', $body, $response, $error);
// 'domains' is the endpoint
// $body is the json
// $response is the returned json response
// $error is errors returned from the curl command
```